# Android studio: Builded jar file not generating some class files

Tags: android, class, jar, build

- Hi i downloaded the vector chat application from this [link](https://github.com/vector-im/vector-android) and i
  imported it as a superate project (By using java 1.7 sdk only it was
  working).
- As a superate project it's working perfectly then i imported (by
  copying manually) this project to my personal project then i got some
  error, by spending some time i resolved almost all errors but now i'm
  getting the error as `cannot resolve symbol RoomPreviewData`.
- This `RoomPreviewData` class file was generating in the jar file in
  vector project (inside of build folder) but in my personal project
  it's not generating the RoomPreviewData.
- For understanding i'm attaching the images to this question. So, any
  one please help me to solve this

**Vector project image**
[image]

**Failure project image**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this was the exact answer, but i'm posting here because it may help others.

1. I changed the package name of vector project as my personal project (For changing package name fallow [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18637004/3142611) steps)
2. Imported (Just copy and paste) my personal project into vector project

then everything working fine......

Answer (score 0):

Am I getting it right that you're building [Matrix SDK](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-android-sdk) artifact by yourself and then importing it into the project? If so, please validate build logs and also see if the file was actually packed into artifact (actually, you may even inspect it as an archive)

Alternatively, you can pull whole package's code from that link and then load it as is into the project